# OPA server with input.method policy fails to allow simple correct request

Tags: opa

I try to get an allow:true for POST request to an opa server, but I get always false no matter what method I use.

This is the policy

```
package learn.test

import future.keywords.if

default allow := false

allow if {
  input.method == "POST"
}
```

However, I get an allow true when I put something like

```
allow if {
  1==1
}
```

and always false for 1==2, as expected.
I am using insomnia to make the requests. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It must be a problem with the input for format.
In most of the cases HTTP method is mostly an internal element not reachable with just input.method. I would try to print the input value and inspect the real value coming as the input.